# How can I checkout a tag, do some changes, and then commit to trunk and retag?

Tags: svn

I have something checked out from `http://svnhost/project/tags/0.3`. I have made modifications in that directory, and now I'd like to commit them to trunk. How can I switch the commit destination? It seems `svn switch` will try to checkout trunk if I use it, but I don't want that because it'd overwrite my changes.

Comment: Off the top of my head... check out the trunk, merge from your local checkout of the branch into your local trunk, check it back in...

Comment: You should have made a new branch from your tag before starting the modifications. Tags are supposed to be read-only.

Comment: @Albireo: It's a small modification, I'm doing it in one commit. I have not modified the original tag.

Comment: It may be a small modification, but it will yield to big headaches when you'll try to reintegrate it into the trunk (exactly where you are now). Branching is a single command, and avoids all of this, so why not do it?

Comment: @Albireo: Just so I can learn, how does it avoid headaches? Is it because I can commit to the branch and then do a `svn copy`?

Comment: You do a merge, not a copy: after committing the edits on the branch, switch to the trunk and issue the merge command, it will bring the branch's modification into the trunk automatically. From there it's a simple commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SVN switch command can be a bit tricky to use, and less straightforward than manually merging your changes into the trunk.  I agree with Forsvarir that the simplest solution would be to checkout the trunk, move your tag files into the trunk, and then commit the trunk.

However, here might be some helpful [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) on using the switch command.  Generally, a good practice is not to work specifically on a tag:

> It may be that you need to make further changes to a release which you have already tagged. The correct way to handle this is to create a new branch from the tag first and commit the branch. Do your Changes on this branch and then create a new tag from this new branch, e.g. Version_1.0.1.

Once you create the branch, you can do a [merge command](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html).

Answer (score 0):

Tags in subversion are actually directories in a certain location.  As such, to checkout a tag, you check out with your URL referencing the directory.

To commit back that tag, you do a normal commit.

To commit back to a different tag, you svn copy the files into the new "correct" tag directory, which you might have to `mkdir ...; svn add (dir)` prior to the svn copy.